# Perturbation by $\varepsilon\mathbf 1$ in a Banach Algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra, $G(A)$ denotes the set of all invertible elements in $A$. Let $\mathbf 1$ be the identity element of $A$.

> Suppose that $x\in\partial G(A)$. Is it true that for any $r>0$, there exists $\varepsilon\in\Bbb C$ such that $|\varepsilon|<r$ and
>   $
> x+\varepsilon\mathbf 1\in G(A)
> $?

I know that this is true for $A=M_n(\Bbb C)$ and $G(A)=GL(n,\Bbb C)$. The proof follows from the discreteness of the roots of characteristic polynomials. I can't think of a proof or a counter example for infinite dimensional cases.

Comment: What about $\epsilon = 0$? Did you misphrase your question?

Comment: @LeBtz Indeed, I made a mistake there. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean to say $|\epsilon|<|z|$ instead of $\epsilon<|z|$?

Comment: @EricWofsey I really made a big mess there, thank you for pointing that out. I should really go to sleep now or so it seems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $D\subset\mathbb{C}$ be the unit disk, let $A=L^\infty(D)$, and let $x$ be the identity function $x(z)=z$.  Note that $x\in \partial G(A)$, since for any $\epsilon>0$, if you define $x_\epsilon(z)=z$ if $|z|>\epsilon$ and $x_\epsilon(z)=\epsilon$ if $|z|\leq \epsilon$, then $\|x-x_\epsilon\|=2\epsilon$ and $x_\epsilon\in G(A)$.

However, if $|\epsilon|<1$, then $x+\epsilon\mathbf{1}\not\in G(A)$, since an inverse to $x+\epsilon\mathbf{1}$ would have to be unbounded near $z=-\epsilon$.

Comment: Brilliant! Just to make sure, the inverse of $f\in L^{\infty}(D)$, if exists, is $1/f$ a.e. right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.